# Showing x amount of comments on post list in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im currently scouting for a plugin for Wordpress which will show a certain amount of comments for each blog entry on the home page and under each category.

For example on the home page:

Entry #3
Blog content
Comment
Comment
Comment

Entry #2
Blog content
Comment
Comment
Comment

Entry #1
Blog content
Comment
Comment
Comment

I hope Ive explained clearly. I havent found what Im looking for yet, maybe Im searching the wrong phrases!

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to update your template with the [get_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) function.

```
<?php get_comments('array_args'); ?>
```

These are the arguments:

```
<?php $defaults = array(
'status' => ,
'orderby' => 'comment_date_gmt',
'order' => 'DESC',
'number' => ,
'offset' => ,
'post_id' => 0); ?>
```

So you would want to set the number to 3. The rest of the arguments are pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the advice, I managed to find the function at  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

However now Im attempting to find the function that just returns the post ID, and not actually print it like the the_ID() function.